# Find the First Letter of a Word, but Keep the Numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been working on a project for finding first letters of a text.

Thanks to @revo, I got the code:

```
.replace(/\B\w/g, '')
```

The only problem with this was with numbers.

My sentence could be:

> Jimmy said, "I would like to eat 10 apples."

The output of my code would be:

> J s, "I w l t e 1 a."

The output that I want is:

> J s, "I w l t e 10 a."

I tried doing this:

```
.replace(/\D\B\w/g, '')
```

but the output was really weird and didn't match up with what I wanted.
What did I do wrong? And is there a simple way to fix it?

Comment: It is not quite clear: what should the result be for `word1` or `Word 12.34 here`? Try [`s.replace(/(\d+)|\B\w/g, '$1')`](https://regex101.com/r/zF2Ewq/1)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest got it perfect. When I tried your code, it took away the numbers all together. The code you used gave this output:                           J s, "I w l t e a."

Answer (score 0):

Considering words that don't start with a digit(but implying the residue from `\w` token, i.e. any letter or underscore):

```js
const str = 'Jimmy said, "I would like to eat 10 apples." ';
const result = str.replace(/\b([a-z_])\w+/gi, '$1');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!